# How do I get the CPU Usage based on a Process ID and not the name of the process

Tags: c#, .net, process, performancecounter

So I have this application which starts a new instance of a java process.
There is no other way to distinguish the different java processes running on my PC besides the process ID.
Also, let's say I were to just put in the name if the process, it would get a random one and it just wouldnt work out well, also what if I sent the application to my friend and the process anem would be different. That would just be bad.

So I been looking around at how to get the CPU usage based upon a specific process ID.
I have no idea how to do that though, I've looked into the `Performance Counter` class but it doesnt seem to take a process ID as one of its parameters.

How do I properly evaluate the CPU usage given a specific process ID?

Answer (score 1):

This might be of some help

```
public static string GetProcessInstanceName(int PID)
{
    PerformanceCounterCategory cat = new 
PerformanceCounterCategory("Process");
var[] instances = cat.GetInstanceNames();
foreach (var instance in instances)
{
    using (PerformanceCounter cnt = new 
PerformanceCounter("Process", "ID Process", instance, 
true))
    {
        int val = System.Convert.ToInt32(cnt.RawValue);
        if (val == PID)
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```